# How to remove empty gap in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[image: Empty gap on navigation bar]

In iOS 7.1, there's empty gap on the left and right navigation bar.
In iOS 8.4 it displayed correctly without any gap.

How to fix this in iOS 7.1?

It's in UITableViewController

I don't use storyboard

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.titleView = UISearchBar()
}
```

Comment: You need to show code, it's not as simple as showing  a screenshot an coming up with the answer.

Comment: It's just a simple search bar in title view, I will update the question.

Comment: UITableView with searchbar? How can you put search bar into the tableview, can you look at the picture it's a search bar inside navigation bar.

Comment: so you literally just plopped a search bar into the title and called it good? did you even try to resize the search bar?

Comment: lets say I did the same thing in my code but like this self.view = UIView() and then I ask why the UIVIew isn't working, this isn't a serious question, if that's all the code you've added and you expect an answer then I just don't know what to tell you, anyway good luck

Comment: Hey, read the QUESTION!. It's normal in iOS 8.4, and the gap appears in iOS 7.1. I didn't call it good, did I call it good in the question?. I need explanation, did Apple change the gap in iOS 8? If you need more information you can comment, Not comment to PISS people off.

Comment: lol, there's no gap change, you  posted your code and all it was is this "self.navigationItem.title = UISearchBar()  .... ta dah! that's your code, that's not a good enough effort, you can't be serious. Have you tried to set the width of the search bar to the width of the view? Am I on hidden camera?

Comment: So you want a project right? I should attach a starter project with that 4 lines short code? And when you open it, you only find 4 lines of code, and you say good luck too? Did you even try to write that 4 lines and prove it yourself?

Comment: yes, that's right, here's what you should do, a quick answer, how about var mySearchBar = UISearchBar() and then you do this magical operation, mySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, UIScreen.mainScreen().frame.width, 40) and then post the results, you can't just plop a uissearchbar into a view and call it good, this isn't JavaScript, it's IOS

Comment: If I can do that, I won't post it here. I tried before asking. Before you answer please try.

Comment: You should probably show us what you have tried before we can answer your question. I'm not answering, that's why this is in the comments, I'm not seeing what you've tried, and I'm seeing just four lines of code. This makes the task of helping you very difficult. You have it backwards, you put in the effort, and we can help you along, but as of now, your question is really too broad given how many factors are involved. if you don't realize that there are may factors involved here, then that's your first problem.

Comment: You are the responder, and you are the one that should try before commenting, I tried all possible solution, from the left button, autoresizing mask, frame, anything I can think of. "I am not seeing what you have tried", did you even try before commenting? So what after this? You will comment "Set the left button", "Change the constraint", "Put it inside the wrapper subview", anything. And I try everything that you didn't even try?

Are you an indigo? Thanks but you should leave now. Your welcome.

Comment: Yes, I'm a very lovely shade of indigo, and you are right, next time, I'll post a full solution and a fully functional app with all the code you could ever want.

Comment: @Larcerax why are you so negative. All your comments are authoritative, and forceful. People learn different ways. Respect that. I wouldn't want help from someone with comments like the ones above

Comment: Agreed, you are correct

Comment: @EdwardAnthony any reason you don't want to use storyboard? That could fix your issue in 2 min flat

Comment: @soulshined Thank you for your response. It's because we are working as a team, and using storyboard will make conflict if someone push change for the storyboard and I pull it from Github. :)

Comment: @EdwardAnthony not that it matters to me, but are you sure you should be exhausting time into iOS 7 before iOS 9 is about to be launched? Have you seen [the latest statistics](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/) on how many users run that? Just 13% as of last week.

Comment: @soulshined Thank you, I have discussed this with our CEO, and 13% seems a big number, based on our starting business plan we need iOS 7 support. I think I will let the empty gap as it is, it's not a big issue anyway. Facebook does the same too on iOS 7 version. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the childish back-and-forth in the comments. What you're seeing is the default dimensions of the search bar. What you should be doing is setting the search bar's frame to be equal to the navigation bar's, but you have to beware of two things: not to include the status bar's dimensions, which get tacked onto the nav bar when the view is displayed, and to handle resizing gracefully, because nav bars (obviously) have different sizes in portrait or landscape mode.

Despite all this, let me just say that putting a search bar in the nav bar is a colossally bad UI decision, and it violates Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to change the search bar frame width to equal as the navigation bar, and also the origin.x to zero, but it didn't work. It seems it's a default position for iOS 7.